# How to call a model without primarykey in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have defined my model class as follows;

```
class Alarm extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite';
    public $timestamps  = false ;

    public function scopeActiveAlarms($query)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('AlarmClearedUTCDateTime', '=', '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'); /\
    }
...
```

My table(ie: vwAlarmActionSummaryYFUserSite)  will return single row for `AlarmId+ UserId` combination.

I call this Model in my controller like;

```
 $alarm = Alarm::findOrFail($alarmid); ---> This is working If i have primary key field in my model.
```

How can I change above to pass both Ids, so my table will return single row?

Comment: What do you exactly want to happen? I can't slightly understand what you're trying to do. And I think you can create another function for what you are trying to do and just return a Model based from your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where clause.

```
Alarm::where('AlarmId', 'xxx')->where('UserId', 'xxx')->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $data =YourModel::where('AlarmId',$alarmid)->where('user_id',$userid)->first();
```